# How to access IP4 server from IPv6-only MacOS client

Tags: ip, mac-osx, ipv6, bridge

My telco provider made some unannounced changes to my iPhone's hotspot settings last week, whereby they essentially disabled my phone's hotspot from providing its clients with IP4 (DHCP assigned) addresses, leaving me with IPv6 only.  I'm 'negotiating' with them to reinstate the IP4 access, but they are taking an extraordinary amount of time to correct their mistake.  In the meantime, I'm trying to see if I can mitigate this problem using some technical solution at my end.

Whilst browsing websites works (presumably everything I've accessed to date is IPv6 enabled), as a result of their changes, at least one of my other applications, which runs over `wine` and relies on a server that only uses IP4 addressing, has stopped working.  So I'm wondering if there is a way to bridge between IP4 and IPv6 nodes.

Is there something that I can configure locally on my MacBook Pro [Catalina 10.15.6] to do this?  Unfortunately none of the n/w adapter's proxy settings handle the traffic generated by my application.

Alternatively, I have a remote, IP4/IPv6 enabled server which I control and could use as an intermediary.  I already have a proxy server running on it, but I've only set it up to handle HTTP(S) protocols.  Is it possible to set it up to forward packets on another port bi-directionally between IP4 & IPv6?  Or, if I were to say, set up OpenVPN on my server, would I be able to use it to bridge between IP4 & IPv6?

Comment: To the VPN question yes

Comment: Would `OpenVPN` need special configuration to do this?  Like options that would not normally be used?

Comment: it will take some knowledge to get the ipv6 part working depending on what the ISP of your server has some kind of limitations.